# Google Apps Script Library with multiple gs Script Files not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Relatively new to Google Apps Script.

Created a Google Apps Script file and have multiple gs files within it.

Deployed a library and included the library in a google sheet.

However, when I call any function from the google sheet, it gives an error "Script function not found:XXX"

I have created a custom menu and calling the function from there. The syntax is as follows

.addItem('Functionality','libraryname.function()')
.addItem('Functionality','libraryname.function')

Help ??

When I put all the code in a single file, it works. Kind of defeats the purpose of being able to add multiple gs files and organize your code.

Have tried calling a local function which in turn will call the function in the library - that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a private function, probe adding an item on the menu, as follows:

```
.addItem('Functionality','youFunctionName_')
```

Notice here that the function name ends with an underscore.

As is shown in the documentation of ***[addItem(caption, functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#additemcaption,-functionname)***, your code *looks* fine, however, check the documentation about ***[function naming](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#naming)*** for see if something else is missing in your code.

Consider check also the rest of the [documentation about custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets#custom_functions) and double-check that you've saved all changes made in your code, the `appsscript.json` file contains the permissions required *(if needed)* and refresh the browser for reload both the sheet and script.